# Hammer JS and History

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I have built the following demo application that allows a user to use touch gestures to move left and right through sections and up and down through pages: http://preview.na-software.co.uk/Demo/FutureLearning2/

It uses Hammer JS for the gestures and the hashchange plugin to track the history of the user so that they can easily return to the same location and use the browser buttons to navigate back and forth through the history.

The issues come when navigating from a page to a section that **doesn't have a corresponding page** as I ALWAYS want to it to default to zero (even if their is a matching page in that section) when moving from section to section.

So if you start at: http://preview.na-software.co.uk/Demo/FutureLearning2/#/section-1/page-1 and then try and access one of the other sections *swipe left or right*, you will see that it returns you to page-0 for that section. **However** this cause a double call of hashchange, meaning that you can't use the browser back button to go back and instead you become stuck on that section and page...

Any ideas on how I can stop this from happening?

The hashchange listener looks like:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){

    var nums = location.href.match(/(section|page)-\d+/g).map(
        function(x){ return +x.replace(/\D/g,"") }
    );

    currentSection = nums[0];

    currentPage = nums[1];

    if( $('.section[data-section=section-'+currentSection+']').find('.page[data-page=page-'+currentPage+']').length < 1) {

        currentPage = 0;
    }

    loadPage(currentSection, currentPage);

    hCarousel.showPane(currentSection, true);

    vCarousel.showPane(currentPage, true);

});
```

Which on hashchange makes sure **both the carousels** know what has changed by passing the current pages and sections to the showPane methods in each instance.

The if statement is to check if the page is valid (exists) within the section and if not it defaults to 0.

In the carousel methods I **also call hashchange** so when a user swipes it updates the history and this **should be prevented from calling itself** by checking if the current hash matches the new hash so it doesn't duplicate it and make double entries in the history.

Comment: Your issue seems to be the `next`, `prev` functions.  They return index+/-1.  As such, when the user swipes right, section-index+1 is used, which equates to a non existent page, and causes the page to reload with pageindex=0.  When the user clicks, back they are being sent to the non-existent page, which then loops back.  I would recommend you update your next/prev logic to ensure it does not reference these non-existent pages. ie, section 1, page 2 the right  links to section 2, page 0 etc.

Comment: Could you show an example? Or perhaps throw together a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in my comment earlier the issue stems from the indexes used to determine the next and previous pages to display.

Currently as it stands

```
this.next = function() { return this.showPane(current_pane+1, true); };
this.prev = function() { return this.showPane(current_pane-1, true); };
```

This simply increments/decrements the index and reloads the page.  As a result, when the user is on page `section-1/page-2` and navigate left/right, they are sent to `section-0/page-2` or `section-2/page-2`.  Once the page is loaded the `HashChange` handler determines the page does not exist and resets the page index to zero, loading `section-0/page-0` or `section-2/page-0`.  As a result (and as you have already determined) there is an extra history entry.

The problem you describe occurs because of this redundant history entry.  When the user uses the browser's back button - it returns them to `section-0/page-2` or `section-2/page-2` - which do no exist and the `HashChange` function redirects them to `page-0` instead.  Effectively preventing the user from navigating backwards.

I would recommend that you update the `prev`/`next` functions of `hCarousel` to check if the specified page exists or reset the counter if it does not.  This is a duplication of the code from `HashChange` but it fires earlier and thus prevents the incorrect load.

```
this.next = function() {
 if( $('.section[data-section=section-'+(currentSection+1)+']').find('.page[data-page=page-'+currentPage+']').length < 1) {
   currentPage = 0;
 }
 return this.showPane(current_pane+1, true);
};

this.prev = function() {
 if( $('.section[data-section=section-'+(currentSection-1)+']').find('.page[data-page=page-'+currentPage+']').length < 1) {
   currentPage = 0;
 }
 return this.showPane(current_pane-1, true);
};
```

As a result the page will jump from `section-1/page-2` to `section-0/page-0` or `section-2/page-0` without the intermediate step.

JsFiddle at - http://jsfiddle.net/2nV9m/
(ignore the quirky ui - it is a bad copy of your code)